# VIM: Is it possible to view pdf file in a split window?

Tags: pdf, vim

I would like to view a pdf file in a split window using gVim, does anyone know if this is  possible? How?

Some details: I just recently started using vim and use it to make notes, while reading a pdf. I write own notes, but quite often I copy text from pdf, so smooth copying would be nice. Currently I need to alt+tab for pdf viewer, go to mouse or arrow keys, select text, copy, alt+tab back to vim. Of course this is not a huge task, but using vim I feel it could be possible without mouse, keeping hands at "home row", and not needing external program alt+tab to...

Ideally I would like pdf to be shown as it is supposed to be. If that is not possible, I will try how pdf shows as text representation using some plugin.

Comment: I use Linux Mint 13 at the moment. This has not been a huge problem anymore, but sure if you know answer, I'm interested to hear it.

Comment: Two workarounds: You can convert pdf to text using a tool like `pandoc`. The other is to use `zathura`, a PDF viewer with a vim like interface.

Comment: A little necroposting, but if you like vim and would like to have the single best PDF note-taking experience, then you should check out Spacemacs with pdf-tools. Vim users don't have to learn much to use it (although getting the PDF-tools to work on Windows is not trivial, it is trivial on GNU/linux and mac), although to enjoy full note-taking power you probably have to learn some elisp. The annotation list is fully hackable (see annot mode and [tablist](https://github.com/politza/tablist) documentation). There are also extensions like [org-noter](https://github.com/weirdNox/org-noter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim is a text editor, so it only edits text. So, yes you can edit the PDF on a binary level, but no you can't view the contents of the PDF as they are meant to be displayed. You can use the `xpdf` package to convert the PDF to text first and then view that, but the results aren't perfect. However, there are some useful autocommands to allow you to open non-text files with their default program when you "open" them in vim. I use these:

```
augroup nonvim
   au!
   au BufRead *.png,*.jpg,*.pdf,*.gif,*.xls* sil exe "!open " . shellescape(expand("%:p")) | bd | let &ft=&ft
   au BufRead *.ppt*,*.doc*,*.rtf let g:output_pdf = shellescape(expand("%:r") . ".pdf")
   au BufRead *.ppt*,*.doc*,*.rtf sil exe "!/usr/local/bin/any2pdf " . shellescape(expand("%:p"))
   au BufRead *.ppt*,*.doc*,*.rtf sil exe "!open " . g:output_pdf | bd | let &ft=&ft
augroup end
```

Instead of `!open` you can use `!xdg-open` if you're using a Linux distro. The `any2pdf` command there is a [script I use](http://connermcd.com/blog/2011/12/07/convert-anything-to-pdf-from-the-shell/) that converts those files to a PDF before opening them. You can edit this if you just want to open everything with its default program. For example,

```
augroup nonvim
   au!
   au BufRead *.png,*.jpg,*.pdf,*.gif,*.xls*,*.ppt*,*.doc*,*.rtf sil exe "!open " . shellescape(expand("%:p")) | bd | let &ft=&ft
augroup end
```

You might also want to look into window managers like [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) or [ratpoison](http://ratpoison.nongnu.org/), which come pretty close to what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think I will stick to using external pdf viewer for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a plugin that will allow you to view the text in a pdf, however I'm not to familiar with gVim so I don't know if this [wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_PDF_files) is applicable to you.

Comment: This works in gVim and shows pdf as raw text. It is not as nice as pdf, so I will stick to my external pdf viewer.